# While loop is not executing correctly in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, indexing, while-loop

I am trying to create a code which will generate a matrix of counts which counts the number of jumps from "state 10" to state i where i is between 1 and 20, where the jumps are modeled under certain conditions. I have reached the following stage of my code:

```
A <- matrix(c(0), 1, 50)
M <- matrix(c(0), 1, 20)
A[1, 1] = min(max(rpois(1, 20), 0), 20)

i = 2
while (i < 50) {
  A[1, i] <- min(max(rpois(1, 20)-rbinom(1, A[ , i-1] , .4), 0), 20)
    if (A[1, i] == 10) {
      M[1, A[1, i + 1]] = M[1, A[1, i + 1]] + 1
    }
    i = i + 1
}
  A[1, 50] <- min(max(rpois(1, 20) - rbinom(1, A[, 49], .4), 0), 20)
```

The problem is that the while loop is not executing properly, and my output for M is always:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I apologize if my code is messy, but I am unsure as to where the hiccup in the logic of my while loop is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `A[1, i]` ever equal 10? It seems like it wouldn't.

Comment: @Mako212 with `set.seed(3)` at `i` equal to `c(6, 43)` the condition is met. This is just an example that can be reproduced, obviously. There are "infinite" seeds with different outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the line where you modify `M` in your `while`

```
M[1 , A[1 , i + 1]] = M[1,A[1, i + 1]] + 1
```

I see that you have `A[1 , i + 1]` as your index. `A` is a matrix of zeros which you modify as well, like below:

```
 A[1 ,i] <- min(max(rpois(1,20)-rbinom(1, A[ , i-1] , .4),0),20)
```

So you change the value of `A[1, i]`; however, you use `A[1 , i + 1]` when you wanna modify `M`. Since you haven't assigned any values beyond i-th entries, then `A[1 , i + 1]` is equal to zero.

So, you end up with:

```
M[1 , 0] = M[1, 0] + 1
```

That's why `M` stays the same. `M[1 , 0]` is `numeric(0)` and so is `M[1, 0] + 1`. You are not assigning to an entry from `M` and you are not assigning a value.

To address the other comment under the post, we can use `print` and check whether the condition for the if-statement is ever met or not:

```
while (i < 50) {
  A[1,i] <- min(max(rpois(1,20)-rbinom(1, A[1,i-1], .4), 0), 20)
    if (A[1, i] == 10) {
        print(paste("i is equal to", i, "and A[1,i]==10 is TRUE"))
      M[1, A[1, i + 1]] = M[1, A[1, i + 1]] + 1
    }
    i = i + 1
}
```

You'll see that the condition is met bunch of times.